# Read and display data from firebase Cloud Firestore in android studio project using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, spinner

I am trying to make an app in android studio using kotlin. This app is supposed to link up to the firebase cloud firestore to store and retrieve data. The main function of my app is that the user is able to choose between 3 different variables (from the "collection" in Firestore) in a spinner, click a button and receive a random object in TextView from the selected variable in the spinner.

In this case, my firestore is made up of car brands (which is going to populate the spinner), and I would like the field variable "model" to be the random outcome (TextView) after pressing the button.

I have successfully connected to the Firestore, but are unable to read and display data from it, both in the Spinner and in the TextView.

I have searched far and wide on google and not found any answers to my problem. Hopefully some of the great minds in here are able to help me.

[The firebase cloud firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV7lg.png)

Comment: You should provide code examples of what you have tried so far and also provide errors you got. This question is way too broad.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you get any errors while fetching data from Firestore? Can you share some of your code?